# Получить список самых посещаемых страниц пользователя

Tags: chrome-extension

Как в расширении Google Chrome получить список самых посещаемых страниц пользователя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Запрашивать табы пользователя и вести их логи, чтобы позже что-нибудь с ними натворить.

*В манифесте:*

```
"permissions": [ ...
   "tabs"
]
```

*В background.js:*

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Дальше вести логи, запоминать, куда ходил, что делал, и, видимо, предоставлять это в удобном для пользователя виде.

**Вариант 2**

Получаем данные, которые собрал сам Chrome, и используем их на благо отечества.

*В манифесте:*

```
 "permissions": [
     "topSites"
  ],
```

*Например, в popup.js:*

```
 var operations = {
    getTopSites: function(callbackfunc){
      chrome.topSites.get(function(url_list) {
        for(var i=0;i<url_list.length;i++) {callbackfunc(url_list[i]);}
      });
    }
 };

operations.getTopSites(function(url){console.log(url);});
```

В лог запишутся самые популярные сайты посещенные человеком в виде объектов. Получить можно заголовок страницы url.title и самы ссылку url.url;